# Prove that $\sum_{i=0}^n4^i$ = $1/3(4^{n+1} - 1)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$\sum_{i=0}^n4^i$ = $1/3(4^{n+1} - 1)$

Attempt:

Let $n =0$ $4^0 = 1 \text{ and } (4^{0+1} -1)/3 = 1$

Assume true at $n = k \text{ so we have} \sum_{i=0}^k4^i = 1/3(4^{k+1} -1)$

The part I'm stuck at is the 3rd step. Can someone point me in the right direction after this?

$\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}4^i$ ?

Comment: Here's what I've set the sum to: $$= 1/3(4^{k+1} -1) + 4^{k+1} = 4 * 1/3(4^{k+1})-1 = 1/3(4^{(k+1)+1} - 1$$ Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{k+1} 4^i = \displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^k 4^i + 4^{k+1}$

Comment: Do I then set it = to $1/3(4^{(k+1)+1}-1)$ ?

Comment: Yeah, set the sum to $\frac{1}{3}(4^{k+1}-1)$ and add it to $4^{k+1}$ and see what you get...

Comment: @j.DavidTaylor Does what I have look correct?